# How to show products Quality rating only in magento?

Tags: magento

I need to show quality rating only in Magento product page. Now its showing Quality, Price and Value, here I want to hide Price and value in front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the displayed ratings in backend. Go to `Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Manage Ratings` and remove Price and Value.